# How can I make the full link target appear immediately?

Tags: google-chrome

In Google Chrome 6, when the mouse is over a link, the target of the link appears in a mini-popup at the bottom left of the window. Initially, the target URL is truncated to about 1/3 of the width of the window. After about 1 second, the popup expands to show the whole URL (or at least how much as will fit in the window). The behavior is the same when the link is focused with <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

How can I make the whole URL appear immediately?

(In case this is relevant, I've observed this behavior with Chromium 6.0.421 from the [Ubuntu chromium-daily ppa](http://ppa.launchpad.net/chromium-daily/) and with [Google's official debs](http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/) of Chrome 6.0.472.)

Comment: Example URL: http://this.url.is/pretty/long/to/just/test?the=behaviour&if=it_works&123456789=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz&USNEOHTNOEHNEOHNTHE=1317419874198417410974897410971491471407419824729242427824872487248742872487248728742487428742874872874287428742874287248385573953939397249972479427249422474729974297424747274742742747474747874287428742874287428742874287428784729287429742984264298426897429842649287428474874298749824742428742879427428972498742982742947242974284642864894264298642982646429864298642984268624964284628648264962498264642928642964928642496294629649428946249862498624964284664468264

Comment: *Check.* The same behavior occurs on other Operating Systems too...

Comment: Incidentally, Firefox 4 followed suit, showing links that span only half of the window. This is [bug #632634](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=632634) (and others), and Firefox 14 will truncate to the full window width instead of half the width.

Answer (score 2):

This flaw has indeed annoyed me for a long time as well. However, according to this bug report, the issue has been fixed: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1455

But it may take some time to trickle down to the stable releases. In the mean time, you should try either the dev or alpha versions.

Cheers!
Scott

Comment: Thanks for the link. As far as I can tell, the fix to the issue you cite *introduces* the behavior that I want to get rid of (and I still don't understand the rationale for this behavior). At least now I know it's called a “status bubble” and where the code is. Hmmm...

Comment: Ah, I guess I lapsed on the second half of your post. Perhaps you could add a comment to that post I linked. It does seem like that would be annoying to have to wait for. Sometimes I don't quite understand what goes on in the minds of some developers. :\